# If two cards are drawn from a pack of 52 cards, difference between probability that both are face cards and drawn with replacement

Tags: probability

If two cards are drawn from a pack of $52$ cards then probability that both are face cards is $\frac{11}{221}.$ But when two cards are drawn one after the other from the same pack with replacement the probability is $\frac{9}{169}.$ Please explain clearly the difference.

Comment: The first one is like picking a card and not putting it back, whilst the latter is like pick one, put it back and put it back again.

Comment: Consider the problem of you have a box with two balls in it.  One of the balls is red and the other is green.  Consider what happens if you pull a ball out, don't put it back, and pull out another ball and ask the question "What is the probability that both balls I pulled out are red?"  It should be clear that it is not possible for both to be red if ensure that both balls we pull out are different by not putting the first ball back.  However... if we pull the balls *with replacement*, meaning after we pulled the first ball and looked at it, we put it back, and then picked again... then...

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

Being able to pick the same card twice slightly increases the probability of getting two picture cards, because if the first card is a picture card, then the number of available picture cards for card number 2 is slightly higher. It also, completely analoguously, slightly increases the probability of getting no picture cards. Finally, it decreases the probability of getting exactly one picture card.